# Reusing a single entity between Spring Data Neo4J and Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Boot 2.2.1, Spring Data Neo4J and Spring Data Elasticsearch to build a graph based application. For the graph, I have an entity class which has an `@Relationship` field to store a set of related entities. For entity searching, I want to use Elasticsearch. I have added the ElasticSearch annotations to the same entity, disabled Elasticsearch autoconfiguration and configured the Neo4J and Elasticsearch repository configurations.

The application starts up correctly but when I try to save the entity to Elasticsearch, I get a stackoverflow error due to the relationship attribute. I have tried:

1. Using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to exclude the field from Elasticsearch.
2. Annotating the field with the `@Field(ignoreFields = {"fieldName"})`

But I get the same error.

How can I exclude the field writing to Elasticsearch?

**Entity definitions:**

Entity:

```
package test.model;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Properties;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.typeconversion.Convert;
import org.neo4j.ogm.id.UuidStrategy;
import org.neo4j.ogm.typeconversion.UuidStringConverter;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Mapping;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Setting;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;

@NodeEntity
@Document(indexName = "entities")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/mappings.json")
@Setting(settingPath = "/settings/settings.json")
public class Entity {

    @org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    @Convert(UuidStringConverter.class)
    @Property("uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String type;

    private Long count;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String[] aliases;

    private String[] socialLinks;

    @Properties
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;

    private String image;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private Date creationDate;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Relationship(type = RelatedEntity.TYPE, direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<RelatedEntity> relatedEntities = new HashSet<>();

    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String[] getSocialLinks() {
        return socialLinks;
    }

    public void setSocialLinks(String[] socialLinks) {
        this.socialLinks = socialLinks;
    }

    public String[] getAliases() {
        return aliases;
    }

    public void setAliases(String[] aliases) {
        this.aliases = aliases;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<RelatedEntity> getRelatedEntities() {
        return relatedEntities;
    }

    public void setRelatedEntities(Set<RelatedEntity> relatedEntities) {
        this.relatedEntities = relatedEntities;
    }
}
```

RelatedEntity:

```
package test.mode;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type = RelatedEntity.TYPE)
public class RelatedEntity {

    public static final String TYPE = "RELATED_TO";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @StartNode
    private Entity start;

    @EndNode
    private Entity end;

    @Property
    private Long count;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Entity getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(Entity end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Entity getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Entity start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete definition of your entity class? Which client do you use for Elasticsearch? Transport or Rest?

Comment: Added the entity definition above. I am using the REST client to connect to Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise to not use the same entity for storing it in different datastores. This is really calling for trouble, as the fields and annotations are likely to be interpreted differently. Define different type for different stores and provide code that maps from one to the other.

I do not know which Mapper you use to map your Entity the an Elasticsearch document. As you are using Spring Boot 2.2.1 probably the `DefaultEntityMapper` that uses Jackson. As this causes many problems (by reusing Jackson annotations on the class for different purposes like storing to different datastores or passing the values out across a REST API), we decided to remove the Jackson based mapper in the upcoming version and only use the [ElasticsearchEntityMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model). This one respects the all the `@Field` annotation values defined on the class, which is not the case for the Jackson based mapper.

So I recommend to rewrite your entity classes for the different datastore, use the `ElasticsearchEntityMapper` and check the different attributes of the `@Field` annotation to define the properties of your class.

Comment: OK thank you. In another application I was able to use the same entity for MongoDB and Elasticsearch without any issues but I see your point. I'll create two entity classes for now.